# Is there a universal way to rotate stuff?

Tags: rotating

The `rotating` package documentation says

> Note that the package uses rotation facilities from the
>   graphicx package. When generating DVI output, users should note that rotation is typically not visible in a DVI viewer:  conversion to, and viewing, PostScript or PDF is necessary.

Personally I use pdfLaTeX for compilation, so I do not encounter this problem. But the arXiv allows users to compile into DVI, and who knows what a publisher might use when processing a paper.

So the question is: what ways there are to rotate stuff and to what extent they can be considered universal?

Comment: no, dvi itself has no rotation commands so you have to include driver-specific \specials into the dvi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The DVI format is described in the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/texware/dvitype.pdf) for `dvitype`, for example.
It only contains operators for moving, rules and font characters. All other things like rotation, scaling, color are done via `\special`, which are specific for the DVI processor.

Unhappily, a standard for specifying specials for different DVI processors does not exist. Therefore I would go for `dvips`, because it is powerful and probably the most used DVI processor. Also, some other processors at least support a subset of `dvips`' specials.